# asp textbox onblur is not firing with autopostback

Tags: asp.net, textbox, onblur, autopostback

I have this textbox

```
<asp:TextBox TabIndex="8" ID="txtUserProfile" onFocus="javascript:this.select();"runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" onblur="GetProfile();"Width="270px" OnTextChanged="txtUserProfile_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

In this text i use a **GetProfile** function at **Onblur** which sends the JSon call to server-side in my CS file and i have to use Autopostbak also. but then my Onblur is not working . is there any alternative for Onblur?

This is my ajax function GetProfile

```
function GetProfile() {
        debugger;
        var profile = document.getElementById('txtUserProfile').value;
        if (profile != "") {
            var prefixText = profile;
            prefixText = prefixText.replace(/'/g, "\\'");

            var count = '10';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "UserRegistration.aspx/GetProfile",
                async: true,
                data: "{'prefixText': '" + prefixText + "','count': '" +  count + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d != "") {
                        var sub = data.d;
                        var sub1 = sub.split('&');
                        document.getElementById('hnduserProfile').value =    sub1[1];
                    }

                },
                error: function (result) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's strange. Onblur HTML event should be working on all modern browsers. Are you sure that `GetProfile()` is actually a JS method?

Comment: Yes! GetProfile is JS function, that sends the JSon data to server-side

Comment: Is it called at all? Place a breakpoint or `alert('Yes');` at the beginning. Maybe it is called but the problem is in a call to a server.

Comment: Yes u r right. Its not firing at server-side. any alternative for this?

Comment: Show your `GetProfile` to a server. Is it ajax call? How are you passing parameters?